# Getting ObjectDisposed exception after closing form

Tags: vb.net

Mainform:

```
Sub Button3Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Form1.show()
        MsgBox("back")
    End Sub
```

This open a new form Form1 on button click

Form1:

```
Public Partial Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(MainForm.folderpath,"logininfo.cfg")
        Dim adptrname As String
        adptrname=MainForm.adptername.Trim
        MsgBox(adptrname.Length)
        Dim args As String

        args="netsh int ipv4 set address name=""" & adptrname & """ source=dhcp"
        Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()        
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh"
        proc.StartInfo.Verb="RunAs"
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True 
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        proc.Start()


        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(MainForm.filePath, proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(), True)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(MainForm.filePath, proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd(), True)


        proc.WaitForExit()

        MsgBox(args)

        MsgBox(adptrname)
        Me.Close

    End Sub
End Class
```

After all the above code runs I get the ObjectDisposed Exception at the Form1.show() line in mainform I cannot understand which disposed object is being called here.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
   at SIBMConnect.MainForm.Button3Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\JONAH\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\SIBMConnect\SIBMConnect\MainForm.vb:line 92
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at SIBMConnect.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
```

Please help

Comment: why is this tagged VBA?

Comment: you should not write code like Form1.show(). Use `New Form1().Show()`

Comment: On what line are you getting your exception? The full detail of the exception should make this pretty clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Close()` in the constructor of `Form1` (which will call `Dispose`), so when you're creating an instance of `Form1`, it will already be in the 'disposed' state (you can check it by reading the `IsDisposed` property).

Just *don't* call `Close` in the constructor. In fact, don't do anything in the constructor other than initialising your object.

Why are you using a `Form` if you don't want to show it at all?

Comment: There are perfectly valid reasons for doing such a thing. You may overload a constructor to take command line arguments sent to main for example and there is an error which causes the application to require termination.